# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Angular and ZF2

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework2

I setup a project using zend framework and angularjs but when I am saving a data I get the error in Batarang Debugger:

```
 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/albums. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

What is the meaning of this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Show how you invoke a request via angular's `$http` service

Comment: @dave Hi. I am just currently studying it and dowload the code here https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-zf2-sample/wiki/create-project